# Why is GHC so difficult to compile?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to compile a recent version of GHC (say, 7.4 or 7.6) on Solaris, compiling using a 6.12.1 binary. However, I've noticed GHC requires an exact GCC version of 4.1.2 to compile itself, as well as many other [requirements](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Preparation/Solaris).

Why are the prerequisites for building GHC so strict? Haskell is so powerful I can't imagine much that couldn't be written in pure Haskell, so why does GHC need a C-compiler to compile itself? Is there a version of GHC I can compile with just a Haskell compiler? Note that I don't need it to generate highly optimised code, even just getting GHCi working will be fine.

Comment: You probably already know this but there are easier ways to install ghc than compiling it from source.

Comment: I don't know this. How do I install a recent version of GHC on Solaris without compiling from source? Can you point me to a Solaris binary? The latest I could find is for 7.0.3.

Comment: @Clinton _Probably_ you don't need the exact versions even on Solaris, but other versions haven't been verified to work there. The prerequisites aren't strict at all on Linux, any sufficiently new GNU toolchain will work there. I've been building all but the very first GHC on a new OS from source for nearly ten years, and apart from it taking rather long (it's a lot of code to compile), it's a breeze. But I'm on Linux. I would suggest just trying to build. If it doesn't work, `glasgow-haskell-users@haskell.org` is the place to ask for help.

Comment: Read that page again. It's not a requirement, it's a recommendation, as in it's probably last version someone actually tried to build GHC with and reported results.

Comment: Bootstrapping a compiler is a general issue with compilers. Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Haskell compiler itself of GHC is written in Haskell, so you can (and must) compile it using a Haskell compiler.  In fact I believe that you actually need GHC itself to compile it, but as you have tried, you probably found out that the bootstrapping process does all of that for you.

However, there is also a run-time system (RTS), which is written in C.  To compile it you need a C compiler.